# Using Python's multiprocessing.Pool(), am I really doing multi-processing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am currently studying '''multiprocessing''' package. Here is a simple code I tried on '''multiprocessing.Process''' and '''multiprocessing.Pool'''.

```
import random
import multiprocessing
import time


def list_append(count, id, out_list):
    """
    Creates an empty list and then appends a 
    random number to the list 'count' number
    of times. A CPU-heavy operation!
    """
    for i in range(count):
        out_list.append(random.random())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 10000000   # Number of random numbers to add
    procs = 8   # Number of processes to create

    # Create a list of jobs and then iterate through
    # the number of processes appending each process to
    # the job list 

    print('number of CPU: ', multiprocessing.cpu_count())

    starting = time.time()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(procs):
        out_list = list()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append, 
                                          args=(size, i, out_list))
        jobs.append(process)

    # Start the processes (i.e. calculate the random number lists)      
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    # Ensure all of the processes have finished
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print("jobs one done in {}".format(time.time()-starting))

    starting = time.time()
    for i in range(procs):
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
        p.starmap(list_append, [(size, i, list())])

    print('jobs two done in {}'.format(time.time()-starting))
```

My laptop has 12 cup cores, so I expect that job one and job two would finish in similar time. However, the job one finish in 3 seconds, but job two finish in 12 seconds. It looks to me that '''multiprocessing.Pool()''' does not actually do multiprocess... Is there sth I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jobs two, you are not using multiprocessing. The `starmap()` distributes the specified method (`list_append`) to each of the arg lists provided in the second argument, but you only provide a list with one element, so each iteration of your `for` loop executes one process. I think you meant to do:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
p.starmap(list_append, [(size, i, list()) for i in range(procs)])
```

without the containing `for` loop.

Note, also, that `starmap` waits for the result, so in the for loop, it waits for each single process.

Comment: ahhh. Thx sir. Understood. One more question, could I write for loop out of starmap? I probably will have multiply for loop... e.g., for i in range(), for size in range()

Comment: You can create the list of args anywhere, then just reference that list in the `starmap` call. It is only required to be an `iterable` with each element being the args to be passed to an invocation of `list_append` (or whatever your real method might be).